# Angular 2, Detect which environment (dev not prod) my app at via server-side

Tags: angular

I am looking for a way to know on which environment i am in via serverside.
for example via the browser i would use `console.log(isDevMode())` which will result in a `boolean`.

would appreciate any answer.

thanks.

Comment: just send the result of isDevMode() to your backend

Comment: Honestly, there are far too many ways to skin this cat for a definitive answer. That said, IMHO the very fact that a front end environment is in "dev mode" **should** mean that the configured back end is the development back end and not the production environment. Never had I had a case where a production environment receives a message from a client to tell it "I'm the development code". It has always worked the other way around.